# I would like to know how to round off numbers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, double

I cannot find any pattern rounding off doubles in an array. I am trying to make a program that will input a double like grades,money etc., and round it off in a whole number.

Comment: I don't know Java but I find this for you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/153753/1542290 so ain't sure how you didn't find any patterns

Comment: 1) itterate trough array and round your number, 2) dont use doubles  for money

Answer (score 0):

There are no short cut available, You need to iterate through the array and use `Math#floor` or `Math#ceil` or `Math.round` to round off.

> Math#ceil - Returns the smallest (closest to negative infinity) double
>   value that is greater than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer.
>
> Math#floor - Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double
>   value that is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a
>   mathematical integer.
>
> Math#round - Returns the closest int to the argument, with ties
>   rounding up

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
private int[] roundOff(double[] doubleArray) {

    int[] integerArray = new int[doubleArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.length; i++) {

       integerArray[i] = (int) Math.round(doubleArray[i]);

    }

    return integerArray;
}
```